# How to manage multiple similar app routes in flask application?

Tags: python, flask

**Alt:** How to use a variable and loop it in Flask app route such that it handles multiple webpages which have similar permalinks (i'm not sure what that is though).
This is a snippet of a simple example to demostrate what I mean:

```
@app.route('/say-hii-1')
def say_hii_1():
    return """<h1>Hello 1!</h1>"""

@app.route('/say-hii-2')
def say_hii_2():
    return """<h1>Hello 2!</h1>"""

@app.route('/say-hii-3')
def say_hii_3():
    return """<h1>Hello 3!</h1>"""
```

You see, only the number changes in all routes, and the return values also have a pattern. My project is much more complex and has 10-20 such routes.
Is there a way, in which I can reduce all of them to just one route?
Some information that you might need: 
**OS: Ubuntu 19.10**
**Python version: 3.7.5**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is flask route parameters/dynamic routes/variable rules

Route parameters allow you to match your application's route to a pattern, by inserting variables with carats <>. If the url matches the pattern, it'll pass the variable into the function your route is linked to.

From there, you can do whatever sort of dyanmic behaviour you want, as per usual python.

As an example, you could implement what you're asking for in your example as follows:

```
@app.route('/say-hii-<int:hi_number>')
def say_hii(hi_number):
    return "<h1>Hello " + str(hi_number) + "</h1>"
```

For more information, you can have a look at the flask quickstart:

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#routing

This is a fairly common use case, so be sure to look through the flask quickstart and guides next time!

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked for me.
And yes, you're right, I should have looked into the guides before creating this question.

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help.